# Wikipedia articles' first sentence and Java

Tags: java, api, text, wikipedia

I have to find the definitions of >200 words. I would like to use Wikipedia in order to search the article intitled with a given word from the list and then extract the raw text of its definition (the first sentence of the article).

In fact, in my project, I have a Jlist which contains words (simple and composed). I would like to find for each word a definition using Wikipedia (I chose this encyclopedia because the words are extracted from a specialized corpus).

My question is: how can I retrieve definitions from a Wikipedia dump? I found JWPL but I did not find an example which helps me to use it.

Another question is: if I have Wikipedia offline (using WikiTaxi), how can I extract definitions from it using Java?

Comment: is this homework? what are you actually asking?

Comment: you wont get code here. You need to emulate web crawler. One approach is find a page where you can find the list of words you want. extract hyperlink for the work and using http://java-source.net/open-source/crawlers/java-web-crawler one of the lib crawl the page to extract information..

Comment: If it's only 200 you'd be better off doing that manually, since you'd still have to go through to check the quality of the results. Wikipedia isn't a dictionary anyway; it's an encyclopedia. If you want definitions use a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia is creative-common licensed (see their [terms of use](http://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Terms_of_use) for what is permissible)

Wikipedia does already have an API, which would probably be better for your purposes than developing your own. More info on the API [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMain_page).

The other thing worth considering is, if you want definitions, perhaps you would be better off using [wiktionary](http://www.wiktionary.org/)? [Wiktionary also has their own API](http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php)

Here is an example API Call to get the wiki text on "stack overflow"

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=stack_overflow&rvprop=content

Here is an example query to return the word "stack" from wiktionary:

http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=stack&rvprop=content

You may still need to parse the output, but it gets you what you want...

If you wanted to do a quick and dirty screen scrape, their URLs are fairly easy to construct. The url would basically be `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/` + a sanitized word (e.g. spaces replaced with _ etc)

An example url made up on the spot would be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow which will take you directly to the Stack Overflow entry on wikipedia.

The body content in wikipedia begins at this comment `<!-- bodycontent -->` and is contained within a div with this id: `mw-content-ltr` You would likely be looking for the first `<p>` tag.