# NLP using Wikipedia (java programming)

Tags: java, api, nlp, wikipedia

Seeking for help in order to make a definitive decision.
For some months, I'm looking for a Java API which helps me to access Wikipedia and get the content of articles. My project is to build a taxonomy of concepts of a given domain.
Details:

1. I have a corpus of domain texts, I extract the first set of terms (that represents the domain).
2. I search in Wikipedia the articles of these words in order to extract their definitions. The definition of the word helps me to find the hyperonym of this word. The call for Wikipedia will surely be done in a java loop.
3. I search the definitions of the hyperonyms found in the previous step to find their hyperonyms, and so on.
4. I draw a graph linking the words to their hyperonyms.

My problem is that for the step 2, I cannot make a definitive decision.

1. I wrote Java code to access Wikipedia online. It succeeds but the speed of my connexion determines if the execusion succeeds or fails giving a set of exceptions. Sometimes, the execution gives me only 2 or 3 articles.
2. I tryed to use JWPL to treat Wikipedia dumps. I failed because I have not enough RAM.
3. I'm now hesitating between a set of Java APIs.

Please give me your points of views if you have already done something in this sense. I made a serious investigation and I found the following links:

1. http://wdm.cs.waikato.ac.nz:8080/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Installing%20the%20Java%20API
2. http://jwikiapi.sourceforge.net/index.html
3. http://code.google.com/p/gwtwiki/
4. http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMain_page
5. http://jwbf.sourceforge.net/

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Can you please give a formal description of the "definition" that you extract in step 2?

Comment: The definition is formally the first sentence of a Wikipedia article. For example for the word 'drilling rig' I need to extract the following plain text: "A drilling rig is a machine which creates holes (usually called boreholes) or shafts in the ground."

Comment: Is using DBpedia out of question? http://dbpedia.org

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wikipedia articles' first sentence and Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233772/wikipedia-articles-first-sentence-and-java)

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar while doing my master's thesis. I don't have the code handy, but I think I wrote a standalone python library (using [python request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html#)) to fetch wikipedia pages.

I recall getting exceptions occasionally. My solution was to spawn off a thread to do the fetches, and if the thread was inactive, restart the fetch process with the current term. Connection speed shouldn't matter, Wikipedia pages aren't very big. The Wikipedia APIs I didn't find very helpful. It's trivial to write a python or ruby script that scrapes Wikipedia.